# Finding the difference between the columns of two excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel files that both have multiples sheets. The two files have some sheets in common i.e they have the same sheet name but different data and values. However, these sheets with the same name have more columns in one file than the other. What I want to do is copy the extra columns from the sheet that has extra columns to the sheet (in other excel file) that has them missing. Again the data in the common columns is different so I cant just simply copy the bigger sheet into the smaller one.

First reading the two files:

```
 v8 = pd.read_excel('Revised_V8.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
 v9 = pd.read_excel('Revised_V9.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

Now reading one common sheet in both files

```
  MAP_8 = v8['MAP']
  MAP_9 = v9['MAP']
```

Now both MAP_8 and MAP_9 are oredreddict. I use this line to get the names of the extra columns in V9

```
  d=set(MAP_9)-set(MAP_8)
```

I'm stuck here. My idea is to retrieve the data in those columns in d and then add that to v8 dataframe

```
  xtracol = MAP_9[d]    # I want to return the values of those columns saved in d
```

I get an error here TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Sorry but I have no idea how to fix this or get the extar columns without using set.

to summarize, lets say MAP_9 has three columns A,B, C where MAP_8 has only two columns A, B. The data in A and B is different between the two sheets. I only want to copy columns C from MAP_9 and add it to MAP_8 without changing the values of A and B in MAP_8.

This is just a simple case but I have more than dozen of common sheets, and some have tens extra columns than the other

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the syntax of operating Excel with Python, but I do know a fair bit about Excel and Python. Now you have the names of the columns that are missing in the other sheet, for every extra column add an empty column to the sheet that is missing it, under the same name. Then load the data from the extra column into Python and write it into the new empty column. To repeat the process automatically, do some simple Python looping such as: 
`For sheet in sheets:

      MAP_8 = v8[sheet]

      MAP_9 = v9[sheet]`
Etc. I can expand on this in comments if needs be.